# Different results for json_encode in Wordpress with php compiled with same configuration and libmbfl version

Tags: php, unicode, compilation

I have an older Debian server and a local install of Wordpress; I'm trying to track down why calling:

```
echo json_encode('');
```

on the Debian server results in `"\ud83dde00"` but on my local install, calling the same `json_encode` line results in `"\ud83d\ude00"` (which is what I'd expect to see on the Debian server too)...

Both versions of php are compiled with `mbstring=all` enabled, and both use `libmbfl version 1.3.2`

Comment: No PHP versions or distro versions or anything?

Comment: The Debian php is compiled from source (php-5.6.33) using `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php5.6.33 --disable-all --with-libxml-dir=/usr/include/libxml2/libxml --with-openssl --with-pcre-regex --with-zlib --with-curl --enable-ftp --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-xpm-dir --enable-mbstring=all --with-iconv --with-mysql --with-pear --enable-filter --enable-xml --enable-libxml --enable-simplexml --enable-hash --enable-dom --enable-ctype  --with-gd=/usr/local` so I'm guessing it must be some other older system library that's at fault?

Comment: I'm not even sure what `\ud83dde00` as a value is? Is that UTF16 instead of UTF8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facepalm. Because I had `--disable-all` the `json` module wasn't being compiled in, so adding `--enable-json` and recompiling then means that `echo json_encode('');` now returns `"\ud83d\ude00"`